# What is the name of a selector method?

Tags: objective-c

If I have a UIButton that has a target such as:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doIt:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What is the name of the selector method doIt:?  Is it the "selector method" or "callback method" or "delegate method"?  I am just trying to get the naming convention down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple call it an **action selector**, i.e., a selector (a string that identifies a method name) related to a certain action (e.g. the click of a button). See the [Cocoa Design Patterns section on the Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Answer (score 5):

The correct term would be (surprise!) **selector**. - because that's what it is.

A *selector* is simply a condensed method signature independent of the receiver.

Comment: +1 more correctly, a "selector" is a the name of a type (identified as `SEL`), and data of that type identifies a *message name*.

Comment: @Dave I think the OP wants to know the name of the _role_ (callback? delegate?) of the selector, and he mixed up selectors and methods.

Comment: selector is completely separate from the method signature. selector is name without types. method signature is types without name

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of personal opinion, but I would personally call it the *"button action"* or simply *"the action"*. I do not believe **selector** to be the correct term, as this is the term used for the structure of the passed-in variable, not the name of the role it plays in the execution of the given method. I think this theory can be somewhat backed-up by the naming conventions used by Apple, who also use the term **action** and not **selector** whenever *a selector* needs to be passed into a method.

Comment: "Selector" definitely is the technically correct term, however I concede that it's sometimes more descriptive to use call it how it is *used* ("the selector is the action", "this is the callback selector", etc).